# CSS Flaticons Show up all Black

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been unable to resolve this.  I downloaded icons and using the demo they all show up back when they should show up in a more colorful fashion

What they should look like: 
http://www.flaticon.com/packs/interaction-assets-2

How it looks like for me:
http://chathelpdesk.com/pp-menu/demo/assets/fonts/flaticon.html

I see the outline of the icon, I am using the default CSS.  The outline of the font icon is there.  Could someone help figure out how to un-black the icons...

Comment: They seem to specify the icons with CSS.   It would be more straightforward just to use the SVG in an image tag: `<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/138/138579.svg">`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.